# Javascript objects and arrays issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on a project and I am stuck at a point that I did not think was that hard. I have an array that looks like the following:

```
    var Coords = [
        {lat: 7, lng: 3},
        {lat: 3, lng: 2}
    ]
```

I need to use a loop to push more lat and lng coordinates into this array...actually about 30,000 more coordinates. (Please note that the current data in there is an example.) I have tried doing:

```
Coords.push(Coords[2].lat = 100)
Coords.push(Coords[2].lng = 200)
```

and that does not help. Any help, with this simple problem would be great! I can figure out the loop just need to know how to get data in!!

Comment: You'd just pass one of those object literals to `.push()` - not entirely sure what you're asking however

Comment: Like, `Coords.push({lat: 100, lng: 200})`

Comment: You shouldn't use an index when using `.push()`. Push will automatically place the inserted element at the end of your array. In other words, only use indices when you are updating/removing specific elements. Use the object when you are using the `push()` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
Coords.push({lat: 1, lng: 2})
```

for pushing new data and

```
Coords[1].lat = 2
```

for modifying data.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Coords.push({lat: 100, lng: 200})
```

You can add multiple objects like that:

```
Coords.push({lat: 100, lng: 200}, {lat: 150, lng: 250}, {lat: 200, lng: 300})
```